# windows 8 app certification testing issue

Tags: javascript, windows-8

hi i am working on windows 8 metro apps using javaScript i develop the app and to test it i use windows app certification kit by testing the app it is finally showing me failed that

```
 Performance test
```

FAILED
    Bytecode generation

```
Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:
    This package was deployed for development or authoring mode. Uninstall the package and re-install it normally.
Impact if not fixed: As a performance optimization to accelerate JavaScript execution time, JavaScript files ending in the ".js" extension generate bytecode when the app is deployed. This optimization significantly improves start-up and ongoing execution times for JavaScript.
How to fix: You may need consider one or more of these steps to fix the issue:
- Ensure that event logging is enabled
- All JavaScript files are syntactically valid; otherwise exclude the respective files from the package
- Please note that you should uninstall all previous versions of the app before deploying
Otherwise exclude the respective files from the package.
```

I tried to solve this but i cant mean while i am using licensed windows 8 pro and visual studio professional 2012  ,but i don't have a paid developer licence account but having a just micro soft developer account .

My main question is to test the app and make it passed do i need any valid paid developer account or general account is enough to test because it is showing package was deployed for development or authoring mode i have read the documents of micro-soft how to test the app i did the same but issue is not rectified can u suggest me some information regarding that.

Do i need a valid paid developer account or general account is enough to test and make it passed. please..

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Store -> Create App Package and select "No" and press the next button. After that the WACK-Tool is started automatically and it will pass the bytecode generation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test your app with your developer license. See detail at [Testing your app with the Windows App Certification Kit (Windows).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx)